# Drawing line between two projected points on map - no line showing - D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I am trying to draw a line between two lat/long points on a US map. I have circles indicating the origin and destination, however when I try to draw the line nothing is appearing. No errors are being thrown.

I'm able to manually draw a line between those points by writing:

```
  svg.selectAll("line")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("x1", projection(data[0])[0])
      .attr("y1", projection(data[0])[1])
      .attr("x2", projection(data[1])[0])
      .attr("y2", projection(data[1])[1])
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "black");
```

But this isn't a sustainable approach since my dataset will consist of thousands of lat/long pairs.

Hoping someone can point my code in the right direction. I hope I'm close since no errors are being thrown. Or maybe I'm taking a horrible approach to drawing lines between points, in which case someone let me know before I am too far down the rabbit hole. Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lriMQC03tQFhIU08LfsS?p=preview) to my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ooLkR8iec5NKx0Ns1zcD?p=preview

You seem to understand the data join based on your creation of the circles

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(points).enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {return projection(d)[0]; })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return projection(d)[1]; })
```

There's no reason you cannot do the same for lines.

```
svg.selectAll("line")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("line")
   .attr("x1", d=>projection(d[0])[0])
   .attr("y1", d=>projection(d[0])[1])
   .attr("x2", d=>projection(d[1])[0])
   .attr("y2", d=>projection(d[1])[1])
```

Notice what i did to the initial data structure, and how I modified it to work with circles vs lines.

By the way, the attribute `d` is for the `path` element only.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I don't know why that didn't come to mind. You did use some syntax I'm not familiar with. Is the arrow notation similar to the `function (d)` I used in the circle creation?

Comment: Yeah it's the ES6 arrow function. There are some subtle differences. If you're not comfortable with them, you can convert `d=>projection(d[0])[0]` to `function(d){ return projection(d[0])[0] }`. See how much more concise it is though?